Errors with the numerical inverse Laplace transform
I want to calculate numerically the inverse Laplace transform by the "Piessens" method of a complicated function given in terms of a numerical integral. However errors occur for functions defined in terms of a numerical integration. For instance, the Laplace transform of $\sin(x)/x$ is $\arctan(1/s)$, if we are interested in making the inverse Laplace transform numerically (not needed in this case, but anyway), we can do
f1[s_] := ArcTan[1/s]
In[2]:= InverseLaplaceTransform[f1[s],s,1.4,Method->"Piessens"]
Out[2]= 0.703893 - 2.20872*10^-18 I

However, since $\arctan(1/s)=\int_s^{\infty}dr/(1 + r^2)$, we can also do
f2[s_?NumberQ]:=NIntegrate[1/(1+r^2),{r,s,Infinity}]
In[3]:= InverseLaplaceTransform[f2[s], s, 1.4, Method -> "Piessens"]

Part::partw: Part 3 of $Failed[UNKNOWN] does not exist.
Part::pkspec1: The expression Solve[3[[1]],s,MaxExtraConditions->All] cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::partw: Part 4 of $Failed[UNKNOWN] does not exist.
Part::pkspec1: The expression Solve[4[[1]],s,MaxExtraConditions->All] cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::partw: Part 5 of $Failed[UNKNOWN] does not exist.
General::stop: Further output of Part::partw will be suppressed during this calculation.
Part::pkspec1: The expression Solve[5[[1]],s,MaxExtraConditions->All] cannot be used as a part specification.
General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Out[3]= 0.703893 + 6.62616*10^-17 I

The real part is the same (which is the only important), but a several strange error messages appear. Could someone help to understand these errors and how can I do to avoid them?

You can't avoid the errors.Imaginery part is zero.Solution is ok.

Those look like coding errors like the error received with  {1,2,3}[[4]] and reflects the inverse transform code has a bug.

@Mariusz Iwaniuk, Thank you, sure the results are the same in this case, but for a more complicated f2[s] without analytical solution I will not be not sure whether the result is correct or not, since I am not able to understand the meaning of the errors.

Add a new question with your complicated example we'll see what we can do.

You may wish to consider numerically integrating the associated contour integral.  For example, the code: i1 = 1/(2 Pi)    NIntegrate[     f2[s] Exp[s t] /. {t -> 1.4, s -> 1/10 + I v}, {v, 0, 5000},     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 600,       Method -> "LevinRule"}] i2 = 1/(2 Pi)    NIntegrate[     f2[s] Exp[s t] /. {t -> 1.4, s -> 1/10 + I v}, {v, -5000, 0},     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 600,       Method -> "LevinRule"}] i1 + i2 returns the real value with 4 digits accuracy without error messages.

$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f1[s_] := ArcTan[1/s]

InverseLaplaceTransform[f1[s], s, 1.4, Method -> "Piessens"]

(* 0.703893 + 4.52787*10^-17 I *)

% // Chop

(* 0.703893 *)

Using exact arguments
InverseLaplaceTransform[f1[s], s, 7/5, Method -> "Piessens"]

(* 5/7 Sin[7/5] *)

% // N

(* 0.703893 *)

Alternatively, without specifying the Method
InverseLaplaceTransform[f1[s], s, 1.4]

(* 0.703893 *)

InverseLaplaceTransform[f1[s], s, 7/5]

(* 5/7 Sin[7/5] *)


Thank you but the problem is not about f1[s], but f2[s]. In this case, the function is very simple and you can conclude f2[s]=f1[s] analytically. But if you take a more complicated function for f2[s] given in terms of Nintegrate, the errors remain.

I mean, the problem is not about the tiny imaginary part of f1[s], it is about the error messages one obtains for the inverse Laplace transform of f2[s] by the Piessens method (I'm only interested in this method). In my example, the function is very simple and you can conclude f2[s]=f1[s] analytically. But if you take a more complicated function for f2[s] given in terms of Nintegrate, the error messages remain, and you cannot compare with any analytical result.
